# Debian 11 grub not showing right resolution

Tags: grub, resolution

I noticed a problem for a while already on Debian 11's GRUB.

The resolution that I have won't work even if I edit `GFX_MODE` or even the other similar command for it.
(My monitor is an AOC LM960 5:4 1280x1024 monitor)

Is there a way to fix this? If not, I guess I should change my monitor.

Also, I use a theme for GRUB from GitHub, but that doesn't make this problem to show up. It's coming by the default GRUB.

Also keep in mind that the dualboot is made with UEFI/EFI boot mode!

Keep in mind that I dualboot Debian with Windows 10 Pro, Windows being the first OS that was installed.

Comment: So, honestly, a 1280×1024 screen is very low-resolution by modern standards. But: that doesn't mean you can't make GRUB use the correct VESA mode!

Comment: have you run `sudo grub-update` after changing the `GFX_MODE` line in /etc/default/grub, or what did you do? Your problem description is sadly a bit imprecise, so it's impossible to tell what goes wrong. What have you done so far? What does GRUB do right now?

Comment: The GRUB does the same things even if i update it or not. Keep in mind that i'm not new at Linux, but kind of new on the command line side...
But, the grub has somekind of issues, i might leave it like this since i want to go mainly on macOS Catalina through QEMU on my Debian 11

Comment: "does the same thing": **what** does it do? we can't really infer from what you state. I know it's kind of tedious, but everything that you can explicitly describe might help, and we can't know what you did exactly when you quote "edit GFX_MODE", without you showing us exactly what that is.